# How to show the posts listing on dashboard or custom page in admin panel?

Tags: plugin-development, posts, dashboard, listing

I want to show posts listing(almost like the default post listing page) on the dashboard page. And if that is not possible then maybe on a new page in the admin area.

This is the post meta that needs to be used for categorising data:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'owner', true);
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'assignee', true);
```

The value for these is the user who owns the post and the user who is assigned to work on that post.

Basically, I want to create a "My Desk" page for users where they can see some posts listed categorised by post meta. I'm fairly new to WordPress and can't get an idea as to how this can be achieved.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You can code dashboard widget for example, but you should provide some code also, what post type do you have, what post meta etc.

Comment: Go through the [WP Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class. That's most of the things you will need.

Comment: @anton Thanks for suggesting that but I don't want the listing as a dashboard widget, instead I want it similar to the default posts listing page(edit.php). The post type is default posts and I have added post meta to the question.

Comment: @Abhik I checked it but one question, how can I use this to display the posts listing in the dashboard area?